# How to change concurrent users = 0?

Tags: sql-server-2012

First I was facing a network issue whenever I was trying to connect to my remote SQL Server. Some times the error was not shown and connected successfully but sometimes it was giving me this kind of error so to resolve this issue, I googled and found [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8FB0nymyns) video. I followed that instructions.

BUT I also did one mistake is that in SQL Server properties, I changed Concurrent user to 1. I overlooked the note above that field written is `0=unlimited`.

After applying changes, my first problem not solved but other problem arise that now it is giving me error like `A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)`

Even admin is not allowed to login to the server. And our work has stopped. So please help me how to change concurrent users back to 0 ?

**EDIT**

1. In services -> SQL Server Browser was disabled. I enabled it from
   properties and started that service.
2. SSMS -> Propertie -> Ensured authentication is set to SqlServer/Windows Authentication mode and restart connection.
3. Again in Properties -> connection tab checked 'Allow remote connection' checkbox. **And here I made the mistake I change 'Maximum Number of concurrent connections to 1' and set timeout to 0 which was 600 earlier.**
4. Windows+R -> type SQL Server Manager 11.msc (11 is the version of sql server) -> In configuration, 'Named Pipes' and 'TCP/IP' both were disabled. so I enabled from properties. Actually in video, In TCP/IP, he said set yes to both Active and Enabled. but in Enabled I was unable to change it as it did not show any dropdown.
5. In that window got to SQL Server Services tab and restart the service.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The video is over 5 minutes long. You might want to edit your question to explain what you've actually done.

If you want to configure the SQL server, you can use the SQL server manager without logging in. You should be able to change connection-related parameters there.

Comment: please see my edit. I added all the steps I followed in the video.

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem is. If you still have access to the connection settings you should be able to set them to whatever you want. Increase the number of concurrent connections and you will be able to login as well, even with the wrong timeout. Restart the SQL server service to apply the values if you can't connect. To change all this, don't use SSMS, use the configuration console.